# Can these kolams/rangoli be drawn mathematically in any programming language?

Tags: geometry, fractals, symmetry

I would like to know how to draw these [kolams/rangoli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolam) programmatically. in any language, what kind of math is required? They are fascinating works of symmetry, thus I feel it should be possible, but don't know where to start.

[image]

Comment: This isn't really a mathematics question, so it may be closed here. I suspect there are folks at http://tex.stackexchange.com who would tackle this problem with the TeX tikz package. You might consider posting it there instead. (If you post in both places please link each question to the other).

Comment: If the OP knows an algorithm for tracing and wants help implementing said algorithm, I'd agree that it's off topic. But I think a big part of the question is knowing what the path of the curve should be. (Interested readers may want to look up the works of Claudia Zaslavsky (possibly Ascher too, I forget), whose son Thomas is also a mathematician!)

Comment: The program Mathematica is also an option. Downside compared to TeX is that it is not free.

Comment: @Suraj the closest thing to your patterns I can recall is a "Hilbert curve", a continuous fractal-space filling curve. You might get ideas about how to modify the fractal to obtain something closer to your designs. There is some code too in the wiki page. It is not the same but could be a starting point. Good luck! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve.

Answer (score 6):

There is a research paper from Kiwamu Yanagisawa and Shijiro Nagata:
"Fundamental Study on Design System of Kolam Pattern"
e.g. here https://www.researchgate.net/publication/237442288_Fundamental_Study_on_Design_System_of_Kolam_Pattern

> YANAGISAWA, Kiwamu & NAGATA, Shojiro. (2007).
> **Fundamental Study on Design System of Kolam Pattern.**
> "Kolam" is a kind of string/knot pattern seen primarily in Tamilnadu
> state of South India, which has a very attractive system of pattern
> formation, that is to say, countless complicated Kolam patterns can be
> drawn following extremely simple elements and drawing rules. In this
> paper, the fundamental characteristic of Kolam patterns' designing
> system is considered by converting these patterns into numbers and
> linear diagrams. Further discussions on the drawing methods to create
> new Kolams will also be given.

There is a set of 16 (*sic*) basic curve shapes at / around each dot which can be represented with the hexadecimal numbers `0x0` .. `0xF`.

[Table 1. 16 Constituent units of Kolam Patterns, corresponding to hexadecimal numbers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OOrP.png)
[image: Image of Table 1]

The shapes are called with names (circle, drop, saddle, pupil, fan and diamond) and can be described by a matrix of 4 bits (0, 0, 0, 0) to (1, 1, 1, 1). The least significant bit is the one which is defined for the lower, right corner in a 2*2 convolution. You have to slant this matrix 45° into the right hand direction, so the center point of the convolution is on the diagonal of the resulting 1-3-1 diamond shape.  The LSB (Bit 0) is then the lower corner, Bit 1 is the left corner, Bit 3 is the right corner and MSB (Bit 4) is the top corner of this slanted 2x2 matrix or 1-3-1 diamond shape. Each bit signifies either no connection (tangent) or a crossing of the lines surrounding the 5 points. So with the four potential connections around each point we can create exactly 16 different elemental shapes which have designated names and symmetrical / mirror properties.

I tried to add a description of the individual shapes in Table 1 and its rotational and mirror symmetrical properties in the following list:

- 0 circle (N°, fully rotational symmetric)
- 1 drop (180°, upwards)
- 2 drop (270°, right)
- 3 saddle (225°)
- 4 drop (90°, left)
- 5 saddle (135°)
- 6 pupil (0°, 180° symmetry, horizontal mirror)
- 7 fan (0°, upright)
- 8 drop (0°, down)
- 9 pupil (90° / 180° symmetry, vertical mirror)
- A saddle (-45° / 315°)
- B fan (90°, right)
- C saddle (45°)
- D fan (270°, left)
- E fan (180°, down)
- F diamond (90° rotational symmetry)

With that "simple" language you can describe & define all possible Kolam pattern's that adhere to the given definition.

The authors continue on to review special properties of Kolam's with 5x5 and 7x7 diamond shapes:

[Fig. 10. Pattern generation and one-stroke judgment. Table 2. Result of analysis on Kolam of 1-5-1 array of points.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wv11U.png)
[image: Image of Figure 10 and Table 2]

Some of these special Kolam pattern's have a lot in common with convolution kernels used in image manipulation, pattern recognition, convolutional neural networks and deep learning. If you look at it from a 45° angle you can see how the convolution matrix and the underlying equations are calculated (e.g. in respect to FFT's).

See here a screenshot detailing the simple 3*3 vector convolution of `(1,2,3) * (4,5,6) = (4,13,28,27,18)` from a recent video by Grant "3 Blue 1 Brown" Sanderson

$(1+2x+3x^2)(4+5x+6x^2) = 4+13x+28x^2+27x^3+18x^4$

|  | $1$ | $2x$ | $3x^2$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $4$ | 4 | 8 | 12 |
| $5x$ | 5 | 10 | 15 |
| $6x^2$ | 6 | 12 | 18 |

[3*3 convolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idHP0.png)
[image: Image of matrix calculation of the given 3*3 convolution]

But what is a convolution?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KuXjwB4LzSA

Comment: You posted links, only.  Not an answer.

Comment: I did not know how to format the images right to convey the message I was trying to get over. Here unfortunately an image says more than a thousand words. I would suggest to read the other excellent research papers by Shojiro Nagata of the InterVision Institute as they also explain how they make this comprehensible to blind persons or persons with learning disabilities.
The original poster may also want to "look" at the implementation of the [OnMouseKolamDrawer](http://www.cityfujisawa.ne.jp/~intvsn/OnMouseKolam/OnMouseKOLAM.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the information, and inclusion of the images.